# why am I getting parse error on input 'x1'?

Tags: haskell

So nroots is a function which returns the number of roots of a Polynomial based on the delta value.
Then I created a function which returns the actual value of the roots of the polynomial. If the nroots is equal to 1 then roots returns a list with 1 item, if it's equal to two then it returns a list with 2 itens.
However, when I try to compile it, I always get error: parse error on input 'x1'
Here is my code:

```
module Main where
main = do putStrLn "Hello World"

nroots :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int

nroots a b c = if delta > 0 then 2 
            else if delta == 0 then 1
            else 0
   where
     delta = b^2 - 4*a*c

roots :: Int -> Int -> Int -> [Double]
roots a b c = if n > 0 then [x1,x2]
           else if n ==0 then [x1]
           else []
 where
    n = nroots a b c
    delta = b^2 - 4*a*c
    x1 = (-b +sqrt(delta))/2*a
    x2 = (-b -sqrt(delta))/2*a
```

Comment: Please post the full traceback.

Comment: Make sure you do not mix tabs and spaces.

Comment: I pasted the code into GHCi and, although it complains about a few type errors, there are no parse errors. (The parsing is done before type checking.) So what you have put here can't be the exact coding that is leading to your parse error.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I posted it just now.

Comment: @RobinZigmond I posted the beginning of my code.

Comment: I see the same thing as @RobinZigmond. As such, voting to close as a problem that can't be reproduced.

Answer (score 2):

Haskell is *strongly* typed. That means it does not implictly convert an `Int` to a `Double` for example. You thus can not construct expressions like `(-b + sqrt delta)/(2*a)`.

You can use [**`fromIntegral :: (Integral i, Num n) => i -> n`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fromIntegral) to convert from an `Int` to a `Double`:

```
roots :: Int -> Int -> Int -> [Double]
roots a b c = if delta > 0 then [x1,x2]
           else if delta == 0 then [x1]
           else []
 where
    delta = b*b - 4*a*c
    sqdelta = sqrt (fromIntegral delta)
    x1 = -0.5*(fromIntegral b + sqdelta) / fromIntegral a
    x2 = -0.5*(fromIntegral b - sqdelta)/ fromIntegral a
```

Comment: but even when I changed everything to Double, it still didn't work

Comment: @SpencerHastings: exactly how did you change everything to a `Double`. Can you edit your question with the new attempt?

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing spaces and tabs. `delta` is indented by two tabs, and `x1` by some number of spaces. Don't do that.

Comment: how can you tell if it's tabs or spaces from looking at my code?

Comment: Press the edit button on your post to see the actual text you pasted, rather than the rendered HTML.